# how to add data from a dialog form using jquery ui into a html table

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a button which opens a dialog box with a form with following fields : name, age and email.
I want that upon clicking the submit button , the data from the form appends the html table on the page.

jQuery script:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
$("#dialog").dialog({
autoOpen: false
});
$("#button").on("click", function() {
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
});

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
var email = $("#email").val();
var name = $("#name").val();
var age = $("#age").val();
var ageReg = /^[0-9]{2}$/;
var ageReg1 = /^[0-9]*$/;
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if (email === '' || name === '' || age === "")
 {
  alert("Please fill all fields");
  e.preventDefault();
 }
 else if (!(email).match(emailReg)) 
{
 alert("Invalid Email");
 e.preventDefault();
}
else if((!(age).match(ageReg)) || (!(age).match(ageReg1)))
{
 alert("Invalid Age");
 e.preventDefault();

}
else {
 $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
}
});
});
```

CSS Code:

```
<style>
table{
        border: 1px solid black
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;

}th{
 text-transform : uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 font-size : 90%;
 border-bottom : 2px solid #111111;
 border-top : 1px solid #111111;
}
tr.hover{
 background-color:gray;
}
.tablemain{
  margin-left: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;

}
.container{
 margin-left: 450px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}
```

HTML code :

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Form">
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text">
<label>Email:</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text">
<label>Age:</label>
<input id="age" name="age" type="text">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<h2>jQuery Dialog Form Example</h2>
<p>Click below button to see jQuery dialog form.</p>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Open Dialog Form">
</div>
</div>

<div class= "tablemain">

<table id="users">
<thead>
 <tr class="headers">
   <th scope="col">Name</th>
   <th scope="col">Email</th>
   <th scope="col">Age</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Aditya</td>
   <td>AAA</td>
   <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: update post with what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append text in a function that expects a jQuery object. When you use append, wrap what you're appending with $().

```
 $( "#users tbody" ).append( $("<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" ));
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
}
```

I'm not sure about all the line breaks and white space -  you might have to fiddle with that some, or even break the build out like so:

```
var t = $('<tr />');
t.append($("<td>" + name.val() + "</td>"));
```

etc...

I stopped looking for errors after seeing that first one. In addition to using text where you needed an object, you were running .val() on strings that came from the .val() functions, and trying to append a nonexistent string 'password' instead of the age field. You also neglected to add e.preventDefault() in the else block after validation, I moved it to the top of the function since it seems unconditional. I'm also curious that you say the dialog closed, since it was giving me an error because the dialog variable wasn't defined.

Also, while it didn't break anything, this structure is redundant (I would just remove the $(function() {} block, which does the same thing as $(document).ready(function() {}):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
```

Fully corrected code follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#button").on("click", function() {

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

  });

  $("#submit").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var ageReg = /^[0-9]{2}$/;
    var ageReg1 = /^[0-9]*$/;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if (email === '' || name === '' || age === "") {

      alert("Please fill all fields");

    } else if (!(email).match(emailReg)) {

      alert("Invalid Email");

    } else if((!(age).match(ageReg)) || (!(age).match(ageReg1))) {

      alert("Invalid Age");

    } else {

      $( "#users" ).append( $("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + age + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" )
      );

      $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );

    }

  });  

});
```

Comment: Tried it, but nothing happened to the table and the dialog box closed